# How to calculate sum of comments through specific id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two table one is `blog` which contains title and description while the second one is `comment` which shows all comments related to specific `blog_id`.

`blog_id` is a primary key for the `blog` table while used as foreign key in the  `comment` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your blog id is 1

```
SELECT comments.blog_id AS blog_id, count(comments.blog_id) AS total_comment from comments where comments.blog_id = 1 group by comments.blog_id
```

Comment: You are welcome, please accept it as correct answer.

Comment: dear i am little bit confuse that how fetch all comments for specific blog_id. in your solution it shows all comments while i want specific records on blog_id bassed comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use join,  count and group by

```
select a.title, b.description, c.count(*) 
from table_one as a
inner join table_two as b on a.id = b.table_one_id
group by a.title, b.description
```

Comment: One suggestion. don't promote people who are not showing any effort.